# Drupal 7, login, "form_build_id" not used?

Tags: 7, users, testing

I write some functional tests for my website.
I have this test :

- go to login page
- post username/pass/form_build_id
- check if the user is connected

In the test script, my form-build-id is "hardcoded". So, I run the connection test severals times and...The user connects each run (whereas the form-build-id does not change)

I don't understand, why the form-build-id is ignored ? 
I check with my web browser, each time I refreshed my page, the form generate a new form-build-id.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. How is the form_build_id ignored? What are you expecting?

Comment: In my test, the form-build-id is "hardcoded". So, he never changes each time I run my test. I don't understand why I can login those Drupal genere a new form-build-id and my test keeps always the same form-build-id.

Comment: In my test (simple bash script), I have this post : name=UserNameExample&pass=PwExample&form_build_id=form-5LrN-HHAJ-ItPaPD5T0ouwdkTA3XLypM6YAx1cOGfh0
&form_id=user_login. The form-build-id is hardcoded. So I can run this test again and again, the form-build-id keeps the same in the test, but I can login to Drupal. I don't understand, Drupal should refuse me the connection no ? because Drupal generates a new form-build-id when he builds the form and this form-build-id isn't the same I have hardcoded in my script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [`drupal_prepare_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_prepare_form/7.x) notes:

> The form_build_id is used as key to cache a particular build of the
>   form. For multi-step forms, this allows the user to go back to an
>   earlier build, make changes, and re-submit.

More than anything else, `form_build_id` is for maintaining the form state through page requests. As you can see in some of the core processing functions (e.g. [`drupal_build_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_build_form/7.x), [`drupal_rebuild_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_rebuild_form/7.x), & [`drupal_process_form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_process_form/7.x)), `form_build_id` isn't required for form processing.

In some instances (e.g. multi-step forms) breaking the `form_build_id` would break the behavior of the form since there is previous data to retrieve, but for the login form there's no state needed to be preserved.